# Box2d filter (maskbits and categorybits)

Tags: java, libgdx, bit-manipulation, game-physics, bitmask

I searched multiple times but I'm not sure why my contact filtering is not working. I used libgdx to create this simple game. The code is as follows:

```
public static final short BORDER_CATEGORY_BITS = 0x0001;
public static final short PLAYER_CATEGORY_BITS = 0x0002;
public static final short ENEMY_CATEGORY_BITS = 0x0003;
public static final short FOOD_CATEGORY_BITS = 0x0004;

public static final short BORDER_MASK_BITS = PLAYER_CATEGORY_BITS;
public static final short PLAYER_MASK_BITS = BORDER_CATEGORY_BITS | ENEMY_CATEGORY_BITS;
public static final short ENEMY_MASK_BITS = PLAYER_CATEGORY_BITS;
public static final short FOOD_MASK_BITS = PLAYER_CATEGORY_BITS;
```

I want player to hit the border and enemies, enemies hitting only player and nothing else, but I have a game loop that adds an enemy every 3 secs, and they go at different speeds and are hitting each other. I haven't really worked with the food so you can ignore that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ENEMY_CATEGORY_BITS` is wrong.
`0x0003` is actually `0x0001 | 0x0002`. That means you are saying

```
ENEMY_CATEGORY_BITS = BORDER_CATERGORY_BITS | PLAYER_CATERGORY_BITS
```

So you say `Enemy` is a `Player` and a `Border` and as `Player` collides with `Border`, `Enemy` will collide with `Border` to.

To set the bits correct, you need to use `power of 2`s, like 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32...

Also always make sure, that both objects collide with each other, if `Player` collides with `Border`, but `Border` does not collide with `Player`, there won't be a Player-Boreder-Collision.
I suggest you to read the [iForce2D Box2D tutorials](https://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-filtering)